# update sql statement with variable

Tags: sql, count

Imagine 1,000 records. 3 Columns. Record number, Color, 2ndNumber. Record number and color are already placed in the database but 2ndnumber is null. I wanted to run a SQL update statement place the number 1 in 2ndnumber for record 1. Have this go up to 40 so recordnumber 40 would be 2ndnumber 40. recordnumber 41 would then start over and place a 1 in 2ndnumber. I want the code to count 1-40 over and over again placing the value into 2nd number until all records have been updated.

I have a table imagine of 1000 records

```
record_number  color    second_number
1              blue     null
2              green    null
3              yellow   null
4              red      null
.              .        .
.              .        .
.              .        .    
1000           white    null
```

Desired result given below:-

```
record_number   color    second_number
1               blue      1
2               green     2
3               yellow    3
4               red       4
.               .         .
.               .         .
.               .         .    
39              yellow   39
40              red      40
41              yellow    1
42              red       2
43              blue      3
44              green     4
.               .         .
.               .         .
.               .         .
79              yellow   39
80              red      40
81              green     1
82              blue      2
83              red       3
84              yellow    4
.               .         .
.               .         .
.               .         .
and so on
```

Like after every 40 records the second_number column must start again from 1 to next 40 as show in desired output

Comment: which database? If oracle, I can possibly think up a solution!

Comment: microsoft sql 2008 or oracle

Comment: One more thing, does your recordnumber starts from 1,2.. i.e. a linear series?
If yes, what is its first number?

Comment: not necessarily. It will be whatever the database gives it when it receives the records. so it could be 10 rows or 50,000 rows. starting at 5 or 199. does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, kinda.. All i can recommend is some smart utilization of MOD function, as I have mentioned in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your record number(First Column) is a linear series, you can utilize it to fill up your 3rd field by utilising MOD function

```
update table set 3rdColumn=MOD(first_column, 40)
```

This will work if your first_column starts from 1, or 41 or likewise.

Hope it helps! .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do like the simple approach @TarunGaba provided. Here is my slightly more complicated approach...

```
;with cte as (
  select * from tbl
), with_grp_number as (
  select *, (case when record_number = 1 then 1 else record_number - 1 end) / 40 as grp_number
  from cte
), with_update_column as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by grp_number order by record_number) as update_column
  from with_grp_number
)
update t
set second_number = t1.update_column
from tbl t
join with_update_column t1
  on t.record_number = t1.record_number


select * from tbl
```

Very good assumption about record_number being sequential... however, with this particular approach, if the record number is not sequential, you can use row_number() function in the very first CTE to generate a sequential value.

Hope this helps... and I wanted re-iterate how much I like @TarunGaba's solution... I'm not trying to steal your thunder... but thought this solution could be helpful.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4b28/12)

Answer (score -1):

i HAVE AN IDEA BUT IT POSSIBLE FOR SMALL AMOUNT OF RECORD I KNOW IT WILL TAKE TIME BUT IT WILL GIVE YOU OUTPUT WHAT YOU WANT..

```
DECLARE @I INT=1
DECLARE @J INT
DECLARE @K INT
WHILE(@I<=1000)
BEGIN
SELECT @J=ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID=@I
IF(@J%40=0)
BEGIN
SET @K=1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE SET SECONDNUMBER=@K WHERE ID=@I
SET @K=@K+1
END

SET @I=@I+1
END
```